# How to change this linux Assembly code into compatible UNIX assembly code?

Tags: linux, unix, assembly, x86

I wish to change this following assembly code into UNIX compatible code without using the linux kernel (or system?) call. (int $0x80)

This code is for Intel 32bit Pentium platform, written in AT&T syntax

```
#cpuid.s Sample program to extract the processor Vendor ID
.section .data
output:
.ascii “The processor Vendor ID is ‘xxxxxxxxxxxx’\n”
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
movl $0, %eax
cpuid
movl $output, %edi
movl %ebx, 28(%edi)
movl %edx, 32(%edi)
movl %ecx, 36(%edi)
movl $4, %eax
movl $1, %ebx
movl $output, %ecx
movl $42, %edx
int $0x80
movl $1, %eax
movl $0, %ebx
int $0x80
```

thanks,

Comment: Any time you're talking about assembly, you need to specify the CPU architecture.  Explicitly.  Even if it's x86.

Comment: thanks, I added that, its intel pentium platform

Comment: Which Unix?  Why do you assume they all have compatible system call conventions?  Or assemblers, for that matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suggestion: Write a C program, with inline assembly.  You could also call C library functions (like `printf`) from your assembly, in order to remove the OS dependency.

Here's an example with inline assembly: http://softpixel.com/~cwright/programming/simd/cpuid.php

Comment: thank you, I just started learning assembly. I will look into inline assembly. (Does that just mean put parts of Assembly code into a C source file?)

Comment: +1. Since there are no standard libraries for assembly, your best option is to call the c library. All you need to do is change the first int to an output function (such as printf), and the second to a call to exit.

Comment: @BeyondSora: Yes, that's most of it.  The exact syntax depends on your C compiler, but you can call assembly instructions and also use names of C variables.  For this case, you can call `cpuid` and then use `mov` to transfer the results from specific registers where `cpuid` puts them, into C variables.

Comment: Umm, I get what u mean. But I am not sure how to do this, the book I'm reading does not say much about inline assembly. How to integrate this code in a C program. Or, how to call a C function in assembly code? THANKS!

Comment: @BeyondSora: I found an example and put a link in my answer.

Comment: And here I went through the trouble of constructing my own example :-)

Answer (score 2):

At the assembly level, there is no such thing as "UNIX compatible code".  Every Unix has its own interface for making system calls.

I can tell you what this code is doing, though.  It is calling the CPUID instruction, then putting the result in the "xxx" part of the `output` string, then calling:

```
write(1, output, 42);
exit(0);
```

If you are using GCC, the closest "portable" equivalent looks something like this:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int cpuid[3];
  char result[12];
  asm("cpuid"
      : "=b" (cpuid[0]), "=d" (cpuid[1]), "=c" (cpuid[2])
      : "a" (0L));

  memcpy(&result[0], &cpuid[0], 4);
  memcpy(&result[4], &cpuid[1], 4);
  memcpy(&result[8], &cpuid[2], 4);

  printf("The processor Vendor ID is '%s'\n", &result[0]);
  return 0;
}
```

For other C compilers, you will have to consult the manual to learn their inline asm syntax.

If you really want to call this directly in assembly, you will have to find out how your particular Unix expects system calls to work.

Comment: thank you! I am trying to run my code on Windows SUA (subsystem for unix application), I am not sure how it implements the system calls. Google "SUA system calls" does not return much useful info...

Comment: @BeyondSora:  In that case, do not worry about invoking the system call.  Just figure out how to invoke `cpuid` using Micosoft Visual Studio.  [This sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xs6aek1h(v=vs.80).aspx) appears to be relevant.

Comment: If it is just calling the CPUID instruction and then invoking `printf` (or similar), yes.  Your goal here is just to invoke [CPUID with eax equal to 0](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID#EAX.3D0:_Get_vendor_ID)