# How does Subsystem for Unix Application on Windows implements System Calls in assembly?

Tags: windows, linux, assembly

Such as this linux system call `int $0x80`.

Does SUA implement something similar?
If so, what are the commands?

this particular code is the one I want to change to use on SUA

```
#cpuid.s Sample program to extract the processor Vendor ID
.section .data
output:
    .ascii "The processor Vendor ID is 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx'\n"
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:
    movl $0, %eax
    cpuid
    movl $output, %edi
    movl %ebx, 28(%edi)
    movl %edx, 32(%edi)
    movl %ecx, 36(%edi)
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    movl $output, %ecx
    movl $42, %edx
    int $0x80
    movl $1, %eax
    movl $0, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the Subsystem for Unix, not an Entire Computer Running Linux.

int 0x80 is a way to invoke system calls on Linux.  It's an implementation detail as far as POSIX is concerned, and POSIX is really what Linux and SUA have in common.  So I'd say that while Linux (on x86) does support 0x80 for system calls, I see no reason why SUA on Windows would need to.  That's because SUA isn't a system that includes that level of compatibility with Linux.  If you build a program on Linux it may use int 0x80 but you may find it does something quite different if you build it under SUA to achieve the goal of making a system call.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to print a line on the screen using assembly. Since I'm just starting to learn assembly. On linux, I can achieve that with $0x80, is there anyway to do something similar on SUA? or DOS assembly?

Comment: You're not really doing it with $0x80 alone, you are setting some syscall parameter too, right?  I guess you'd need to figure out how to do syscalls in assembly on Windows.  Which syscall were you using on Linux?

Comment: Cool.  Adding substantial comments to your ASM would help too.  Another idea to explore is to take this up a level and talk about what you're actually trying to accomplish.  Maybe it can be done without ASM.

Comment: yes, I can figure out cpuid without using ASM, but just with Visual Studio. But, I am curious as whether or not it is possible with ASM, and particularly on SUA.

Comment: SUA doesn't turn Windows into not-Windows. If you want to do things on Windows then use the Windows ABI.

Comment: is there any reference site? The book I have only teaches linux assembly

Comment: Intel has a page that seems to describe exactly what you want: CPUID on Visual Studio: http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/cpuid-for-x64-platforms-and-microsoft-visual-studio-net-2005/

Comment: @John: Because he already has an answer to [his other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6318402/103167) showing how to use `cpuid` from a C program using inline assembly, it seems that this question is about Windows syscalls from assembly, rather than about `cpuid`.

Answer (score 0):

Windows does have system calls, analogous to linux, in order to access kernel services from user-mode.  Normally you don't use the `syscall` or `int` instruction directly though, you use one of the wrappers in `ntdll.dll`.

There definitely isn't any 1:1 correlation between linux system calls and windows system calls.

The various subsystems (Win32, e.g. kernel32.dll and user32.dll and POSIX, e.g. the SUA libraries) call `ntdll.dll` functions when they need to make syscalls.